# Computation to differentiate a determinant

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, matrix-analysis, determinants, matrix-inverse

Consider a positive Hermitian $N \times N$ matrix $A$ with complex valued coefficients. We list its eigenvalues in increasing order and with their multiplicities, $\mu_{1} \leq \mu_{2} \leq \cdots \leq \mu_{N}$ and consider the one parameter family of matrices $A+\lambda$. How can I verify that for any $\lambda>-\mu_{1}$, the following
$$
\frac{d}{d \lambda} \log (\operatorname{det}(A+\lambda))=\operatorname{trace}(A+\lambda)^{-1}
$$
holds?
(This formula motivates the definition of a relative determinant.)

Comment: Just write the determinant as the product of the eigenvalues.

Comment: This is basically the same argument as above but it is worth recalling the old saw that the spectral theorem makes some results (on s.a. matrices or operators--even unbounded) just as easy as the scalar case.  On assumes that the matrix, in this case, is self-adjoint and the diagonal elements whirl around completely independently of each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $A+\lambda$ are $\{\mu_j+\lambda\}$ which are positive by assumption. So

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda} \log\det(A+\lambda)
 = \frac{d}{d\lambda} \sum_j \log (\lambda+\mu_j)
 = \sum_j (\lambda+\mu_j)^{-1},
$$
which is the sum of the eigenvalues (i.e. the trace) of
$(A+\lambda)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 6):

The condition $\lambda+\mu_1>0$ ensures that $M(\lambda)=A+\lambda $ is invertible, and then one can use [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda} \det M(\lambda) = \det M(\lambda) \operatorname{tr} \left(M(\lambda)^{-1} \frac{d}{dt} M(\lambda)\right),$$
to find that
$$\frac{d}{d \lambda} \ln \operatorname{det}(A+\lambda)=\frac{1}{\det(A+\lambda)}\frac{d}{d\lambda}\det(A+\lambda)=\text{tr}\,(A+\lambda)^{-1}.$$
This holds even if $A$ is not Hermitian, and cannot be diagonalized, as long as $A+\lambda$ is invertible.

Comment: Though since all functions involved are analytic, showing the formula holds for diagonalizable matrices should be enough?